# How to change URL Custom Page?

Tags: customization, pages, urls, rewrite-rules

My Page Custom URL: **http://abcd.com/watch?name=video-title**

How can I change this url to **http://abcd.com/watch/video-title**

where `watch` is a custom page?

My `functions.php` code:

```
function create_new_url_querystring()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^watch/([^/]*)$',
        'index.php?page_id=3&name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

}
add_action('init', 'create_new_url_querystring');
```

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. Did you try `add_rewrite_rule()` ?

Comment: Thank you @birgire. Yes i try but i can't do it.

Comment: Please update your question with that code and explain what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the reserved public query variable `name` as your custom one.

It can e.g. affect the *canonical redirect* by setting `page_id` and `name` for a different page.

Change it to something else to avoid possible name collision, like `kenan_video_slug`:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^watch/([^/]*)$',
    'index.php?pagename=watch&kenan_video_slug=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

Note that your rewrite will override the content pagination for the `watch` page.

Remember to flush the rewrite rules.